# How do I search an array that's nested in an array of objects in Elastic?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have an Elastic index that contains objects structured like this:

```js
{
  dogs: [
    {
      name: 'wiener dog',
      id: 2,
      cats: [
        {
          name: 'mean cat',
          id: 5,
        },
        ...
      ],
    },
    ...
  ],
  ...
}
```

**My question is:** How do I search against this index for all documents that include a particular `id` in `cats`? A single match is fine.

**What I have tried:** I have tried many different queries, including nesting on `dogs`, and nesting on both `dogs` and `cats`. I have tried accessing the property directly via `dogs.cats.id`, and all combinations of the above. Here is an example in NEST:

```cs
query &= mst.Nested(n => n
    .Path("dogs")
    .Query(q => q
        .Nested(n => n
            .Path("dogs.cats")
            .Query(q => q
                .Terms(t => t
                    .Field("dogs.cats.id")
                    .Terms(catIds.ToList())
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

I have also tried with a single `Nested` with `Field` set to `cats.id` with no luck.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated. Changing the data structure at this point would be a much larger effort, and would be avoided if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your information, I assume that the use of **[NestedQuery](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html)** is ideal.

```
PUT bug_reports
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "dogs": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "cats": {
            "type": "nested"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST bug_reports/_doc/1
{
   "dogs": [
    {
      "name": "wiener dog",
      "id": 1,
      "cats": [
        {
          "name":"red cat",
          "id": 4
        },
        {
          "name":"mean cat",
          "id": 5
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


POST bug_reports/_doc/2
{
   "dogs": [
    {
      "name": "none dog",
      "id": 2,
      "cats": [
        {
          "name":"mean cat",
          "id": 5
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

GET bug_reports/_search?filter_path=hits.hits
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "dogs",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "dogs.cats",
                "query": {
                  "terms": {
                    "dogs.cats.id": [
                      4
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "dogs.cats",
                "query": {
                  "terms": {
                    "dogs.cats.id": [
                      5
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: See my edit above: This is almost exactly what I tried. The only difference I guess is I am passing an array of ids into the term.

Comment: should these ids match one or more documents?  what result do you get when you run the query?

Comment: If I pass in 3 cat ids, each document should have at least 1 of the 3 (doesn't matter which dog they are in). Running my query returns no results regardless of if they have the id I pass in. Thanks!

Comment: Using list and Terms Query shouldn't work as TermsQuery is an OR.
If I understood correctly you would have to have a clause for each item on the list (I don't know if the list is big).
I edited my example. As I understand it, if I have two documents, I should only return the one that has all the items in the list.